# Error on constructor while saving form into the database

Tags: magento2.3, database, php-7.2, construct, help-wanted

Here is my save.php

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;
use Mageplaza\Menu\Model\PostFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Save extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $postFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory, PostFactory $postFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->postFactory = $postFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
   $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

   
   $postModel = $this->postFactory->create();
   $postModel->setData($postData);

   
   try {
       $postModel->save();
       $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('New post added.'));
       $this->_redirect('*/*/');
       return;
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('An error occurred while saving the post.'));
       $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', ['id' => $postModel->getId()]);
       return;
   }
}
    }
}
```

When i tries to run this action the error was occured like this

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Mageplaza\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor, Too few arguments to function Mageplaza\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save::__construct(), 2 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\generated\code\Mageplaza\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor.php on line 14 and exactly 3 expected
```

Please help me to resolve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please replace this code and compile it

```
public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory, PostFactory $postFactory)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->postFactory = $postFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $resultPageFactory, $postFactory);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help